# How to fix 'return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type' in C

Tags: c

Working to re-write the strchr method defined in string.h.
And i am getting "return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type"

```cpp
char* strchr(const char* str, int character){
        int idx = 0;
        do{
                if (str[idx] == character){
                        return &str[idx]; // This line has the error
                }
                idx++;
        } while (str[idx] != '\0');

        return NULL;
} // any help would be great, thanks.
```

Comment: They do it with a cast: https://opensource.apple.com/source/BerkeleyDB/BerkeleyDB-18/db/clib/strchr.c.auto.html

Comment: Why is `strchr` defined this way?  If it returns a pointer to an element of `str` it *should* return a `const char *`.  It looks like it's been this way since at least C89.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes:

1. Since you can't change the prototype you must cast away the const in the `return`: `return (char *) &str[idx];`.
2. Your implementation has a bug, consider happens if `strchr("", 'a')` is called. You increment `idx` inside the body of the loop, before NUL-checking so it will step beyond the end of the string.